# Menu that Segues to SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, menu, sprite-kit

I have a working game that is just like Flappy Bird. I have a regular view controller for the menu and a game view controller for the game. How do you segue from the ViewController to SpriteKit with a button?

```
import SpriteKit

class Games: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var gamePlayScence = SKScene()

    var score = 0
    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
    var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()

    var bird = SKSpriteNode()
    var bg = SKSpriteNode()
    var labelHolder = SKSpriteNode()

    let birdGroup:UInt32 = 1
    let objectGroup:UInt32 = 2
    let gapGroup:UInt32 = 0 << 3

    var gameOver = 0

    var movingObjects = SKNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)

        self.addChild(movingObjects)

        makeBackground()

        self.addChild(labelHolder)

        scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
        scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height - 70)
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 11
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)



        let birdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img 2/flappy1.png")
        let birdTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img 2/flappy2.png")

        let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([birdTexture, birdTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.1)
        let makeBirdFlap = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)

        bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture)
        bird.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        bird.runAction(makeBirdFlap)

        bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height / 2)
        bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        bird.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = birdGroup
        bird.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = objectGroup
        bird.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gapGroup


        bird.zPosition = 10

        self.addChild(bird)

        let ground = SKNode()
        ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
        ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
        self.addChild(ground)

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("makePipes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func makeBackground() {


        let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img 2/bg.png")


        let movebg = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 9)
        let replacebg = SKAction.moveByX(bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
        let movebgForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([movebg, replacebg]))

        for var i:CGFloat=0; i<3; i++ {

            bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
            bg.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width/2 + bgTexture.size().width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
            bg.size.height = self.frame.height


            bg.runAction(movebgForever)


            movingObjects.addChild(bg)


        }


    }

    func makePipes() {

        if (gameOver == 0) {

            let gapHeight = bird.size.height * 4

            let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 2)

            let pipeOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.size.height / 4

            let movePipes = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 2, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width / 100))

            let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            let moveAndRemovePipes = SKAction.sequence([movePipes, removePipes])



            let pipe1Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img 2/pipe1.png")

            let pipe1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: pipe1Texture)
            pipe1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + pipe1.size.height / 2 + gapHeight / 2 + pipeOffset)
            pipe1.runAction(moveAndRemovePipes)
            pipe1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipe1.size)
            pipe1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            pipe1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            pipe1.zPosition = 8
            movingObjects.addChild(pipe1)


            let pipe2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img 2/pipe2.png")
            let pipe2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: pipe2Texture)
            pipe2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - pipe2.size.height / 2 - gapHeight / 2 + pipeOffset)
            pipe2.runAction(moveAndRemovePipes)
            pipe2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipe2.size)
            pipe2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            pipe2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            pipe2.zPosition = 8
            movingObjects.addChild(pipe2)

            let gap = SKNode()
            gap.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + pipeOffset)
            gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(pipe1.size.width, gapHeight))
            gap.runAction(moveAndRemovePipes)
            gap.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            gap.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gapGroup
            gap.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = gapGroup
            gap.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = birdGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(gap)

        }

    }

    // Update - removed ! after SKPhysicsContact

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == gapGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == gapGroup {

            score++

            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"



        } else {

            if gameOver == 0 {

                gameOver = 1

                movingObjects.speed = 0

                gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
                gameOverLabel.fontSize = 30
                gameOverLabel.text = "Game Over! Tap to play again."
                gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
                gameOverLabel.zPosition = 11
                labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)

            }

        }


    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {



        if (gameOver == 0) {

            bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 50))

        } else {



            score = 0
            scoreLabel.text = "0"

            movingObjects.removeAllChildren()

            makeBackground()

            bird.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
            bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

            labelHolder.removeAllChildren()

            gameOver = 0

            movingObjects.speed = 1


        }

    }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't contain a question. Read [mcve] and try to reduce your code to the minimum code required to show the behaviour you see.

Comment: Sorry, I am just starting to use stack over flow. My question is how does one create a functional segue from a regular UI view to a SK view in the form of a button. @BenjaminW.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add the question :)